# Calculate model accuracy confidence intervals from caret model object?

Tags: confidence-interval, model, caret

I am trying to generate 95% confidence intervals for the accuracy predictions on the trained data set using the caret package and interface.

Some dummy code:

```
library(earth)
```

## Set control parameters

```
Tcontrolparam.Acc = trainControl("cv", savePredictions = TRUE,  classProbs = T, returnResamp = "final")
```

## Set output to factor - classification - dw about names - just dummy data

```
trees$class = c(rep(c("John","Steve"),nrow(trees)/2),"Steve")
```

## Model 1 using glm model

```
set.seed(0)
x = train(x = select(trees, -class), y = trees$class,
                                  method = "glm",
                                  metric = "Accuracy",
                                  trControl = Tcontrolparam.Acc)
```

## Model 2 using MARS (earth) model

```
y = train(x = select(trees, -class), y = trees$class,
          method = "earth",
          metric = "Accuracy",
          trControl = Tcontrolparam.Acc)
```

## Combining models into list and generating resampled results

```
Model.Objects.List = list(x,y)

Results = resamples(Model.Objects.List)

Summary.Results = summary(Results)
```

The code above and specifically Summary.Results gives a mean value for accuracy across the resamples but not the confidence intervals. Is there an easy way of computing confidence intervals using caret or externally across many models?

Comment: Accuracy is doubtful as a measure of your predictive power in the first place: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) and [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)

Comment: @StephanKolassa HI Stephan, if I was to use ROC to tune my model I still do not know how to get the confidence intervals in this user interface.

Comment: See [Related post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015605/getting-confidence-intervals-on-prediction-from-carettrain), also the [closed issue on github](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/187), in which Max Kuhn states that this is now possible in the newer tidymodels package.